# How should I design two models `A` and `B` so there is a 3rd table that associate many rows in `A` to one row in `B`?

Tags: sql, go-gorm

(This question is specific to `go-gorm`. I know how to do this in raw SQL.)

Let me put my question in this over simplified form:

Say I already have:

- table A, say `kids`
- table B, say `moms`

NOTE: I am not allowed to change each structure.

How do design these two modles, such that it end up another table `bond` where each row is a `kid_id` and a `mom_id`?

Thanks

Comment: Many to many allows one `kid` record to be associated with multiple `mom` records.

Comment: You could make the `kid_id` unique in the third table.

Comment: Great. Assuming you are not talking about touching the thrid table directly, how do I do that with `gorm`?

Comment: Please clarify, which circumstances are fixed (table definition and/or model for table 1, 2, 3, 4, ...) and which degree of freedom is left. Is it ok to create a new table?

Comment: table A (`kids`) and table B (`moms`) are fixed - think of them owned by other people I never talk to. It is OK to create new table - I know how to do this in raw SQL. The question is specific to `gorm`.